Ionic 3 app not installing on Android 12/13 after adding ionic-native Push plugin
Description:
I am developing an Ionic 3 app and recently added the ionic-native Push plugin. After making this change,it work on Android version less than 12 But I encounter an issue when trying to install the app-debug.apk on an Android device running Android 12 or 13. The installation fails with the error:
"INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl128248252.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #96): com.adobe.phonegap.push.FCMService: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present."
Steps to Reproduce:

Build the app using "ionic cordova run android".
Try to install the generated APK (app-debug.apk) on an Android device running Android 12 or 13, i got error like "app not installed as package appears to be invalid".

Error Message:
Here is the full error message I receive when trying run command "ionic cordova run android":
Find Error Imahe Below
